Error dialog box when click on button to run API call through APEX class using LWC - Error [NoErrorObjectAvailable]
Hi I am new to salesforce development so please bear with me.
I created an LWC to create table inside "accounts" object that shows some data. This data is loaded through an external API call which is working fine.
Now I want to add a button in each row of the table and clicking on that button will run another API call. When I click on this button I get the error that is shown in the image below

In my instanceList.js I have:
<template>
<lightning-card title="Instances">
    <lightning-button label="Create New Trial Instance" onclick={handleCreateInstance}></lightning-button>

    <template if:true={instances}>
        <lightning-datatable 
            key-field="id" 
            data={instances} 
            columns={columns}
            onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </template>
    <template if:true={error}>
        <div class="slds-text-color_error" role="alert">
            {error}
        </div>
    </template>
</lightning-card>

and in my instanceList.js I have
handleRowAction(event) {
    const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
    const row = event.detail.row;

    switch (actionName) {
        case 'deleteInstance':
            this.handleDelete(row);
            break;
        case 'openLink':
            this.handleOpenLink(row);
            break;
        default:
    }
        
    
}
handleOpenLink(instance) {
    console.log(instance.instance_id);
    getJwt({ instanceId: instance.instance_id })
        .then(jwt => {
            console.log(jwt);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

in the apex class I have:
@AuraEnabled
public static void getJwt(String instanceId) {
    
        System.debug('here 0');
}

The loading of the table with data is working fine so I know that part is working, the error appears when i click on the button to trigger handleOpenLink(). It gets triggered, I see the console.log(instance.instance_id); output but after that the error dialog box appears. I have other functions in the same Apex class too to load the table and they are working fine. Can anyone guide me what am i doing wrong here.
I checked the debug logs in salesforce. Nothing appears there as well.
This is how the table looks:


Hello, it might be that you need a return type for your getJwt apex method.  In a test environment consider returning String rather than void.

@PeterNoges I tried that as well but didn't work

I found the Issue,
I was not importing the apex class function.
getJwt that was defined in Apex class was not imported in instanceList.js.
Adding import getJwt from '@salesforce/apex/InstanceService.getJwt'; at the top fixed the issue
